# Add custom template after_body_start in adminhtml

Tags: magento-1.9, template

How to add a custom template just after body tag in adminhtml in magento?

All working fine if I am trying to add custom template in head but failing if I am doing the same to include custom template in body of adminhtml page.

Here is my code for adminhtml layout file:

```
<default>
  <reference name="after_body_start">
    <block type="adminhtml/template" template="gtm/after_body_start.phtml" name="after_body_start_script" as="after_body_start_script"/>
  </reference>
</default>
```

Here is my code for the file present at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/gtm/after_body_tag.phtml

```
<?php
  Mage::log('control coming here', null, 'custom_log_file.log');
?>
```

If the control logs in my custom log file, It will work for the code I will write in it but I cannot see the log file updating.
It seems that either I am using wrong reference for adminhtml to include a custom template after body start or I am missing to include the block to be included somewhere!
Please guide me to get this done!

Answer (score 0):

There is no any reference like `after_body_start` for admin.

Instead of this you can use `before_body_end` OR if you want this in top of the page then you can use reference name `notifications` and the code must be like :

```
<default>
   <reference name="before_body_end">
       <block type="adminhtml/template" template="gtm/after_body_start.phtml" name="after_body_start_script" as="after_body_start_script"/>
   </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish for the help. I do also thought of to move like that if no solution for after_body_start in adminhtml.

Is there anything wrong if I quote my code directly just after the <body> tag in the file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml so as to get my codes just body starts?